# Import pandas on webhost

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use pandas on my site, so I uploaded pandas folder from site-packages folder to my host's directory via ftp. I imported pandas in the python cgi script but I got this error:

```
File "/data/web/my sites folder/packs/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
 ImportError: cannot import name hashtable
 malformed header from script. Bad header=cannot import name hashtable: test.py
```

test.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
site_packages = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '/data/web/my sites folder/packs')
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)
sys.path.insert(0, site_packages)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#pandas example stuff
```

I haven't got an SSH acces to the host, so I have no idea how should I solve this.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you running the same OS and version of Python as is on the server?

Comment: I use win7 and python 2.7, I think the server has python 2.6 and the OS is debian or ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

`pandas`, like `numpy` and many other modules, is not written in pure Python - it has components written in C and Cython that get compiled into version- and platform-specific libraries during the build process. Therefore, you can't use `pandas` compiled for Python 2.7 on a box running 2.6, and likewise you can't use a version compiled for Windows on a Linux server. You're going to need to find a different method of installing new modules on your server, as your current method simply won't work. Your best bet is to contact your hosting provider and find out what options they have, because if they support running Python programs there must be a mechanism for locally installing extra modules.